# Trim user entered excerpt in content.php wordpress file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom function to trim the excerpt:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 10; }
```

and the filter to apply it:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

and then I get the excerpt in my content.php as:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

The function works if not custom user entered excerpt is found. so basically grabs the first 10 words from the blog post content. But it doesn't trim when I custom enter the excerpt. Any ideas to display the trimmed version of the user entered excerpt in the blog post page?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I custom enter the excerpt"? What is the process you are going through to custom enter the excerpt?

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/1UwZhdx)

Comment: Add new post > Add content > Add excerpt. So basically if I leave the excerpt field empty when creating a new post, the custom_excerpt_lenght function works.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got what I needed. So I just wanted to reduce the trimmed excerpt to a lower character count. I just added to my functions page:

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    $more = '&hellip;';
    return $more; 
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' ); //displays ... after the excerpt

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 30; //number of words to display in the excerpt
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 ); //999 si it filters at the end
```

And then in my content.php page:

```
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,80);?></p>
```

That way I get no more than 80 characters in my blog post list page and 30 words on my individual blog post page (content-single.php).

Comment: Just adding a comment to say this really helped, thank you. Not sure why WP wouldn't include a built in function to trim custom excerpts

Comment: substr did it for me, when it comes to excerpts that the user has entered manually and that are not auto generated by WP. For automatically generated excerpts the filter excerpt_length works nicely.